# nested javascript makes comment system slow

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've created a system which allows users to view photos and comment them. If the user clicks on an album, he is sent to a page where the first photo (with comments and replies of the comment) is displayed in the center of the page. On the right side all the other photos of the current album will be listed.

This part is done with simple PHP-Code and comes with every new page load.

When the user clicks on one of the photos now (that are listed on the right side) not the entire page, but only the corresponding elements (photo, comments, replies of the comments) will be loaded via Ajax.

This works well so far. Here is the corresponding code for better understanding:

PHP:

```
// Get data from the database to display the current photo and its comments on the page
// Some Code

// Here is the included file to get the HTML for the comments --> Problem number 2

// List all the photos of the current album at the right side
$album_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['id']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE id='$album_id' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $u = $row['user'];
}

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM photos WHERE album_id='$album_id'"; 
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $filename = $row['filename'];

    $style_list_right .= '<div id="right_'.$id.'" onclick="getPhotos(\''.$album_id.'\',\''.$id.'\',\''.$u.'\')">';
    $style_list_right .=     '<img src="'.USERFILES . $u.'/'.$filename.'" />';
    $style_list_right .= '</div>';
}
```

If the user clicks on a photo the function getPhotos() will be called

```
function getPhotos(album,photo,user){
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "path/some_php_file.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            // Get a string from PHP delimited by |
            var photo = ajax.responseText.split("|");

            // Change the HTML to display the photos

            // Call the Function to get the comments
            getComments(photo);
        }
    }
    ajax.send("show=photos&photo="+photo);
}

function getComments(photo) {
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "path/some_php_file.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            // Get a string from PHP delimited by |
            var comments = ajax.responseText.split("|||");
            for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){ 
                var comment = comments[i].split("|");
                if(comment[1] == "<?php echo $log_username; ?>") {      // If the user is the author of the comment
                    // Change the HTML of the comments
                    _('comment_'+photo).innerHTML += '<?php echo $comments_html; ?>';    // This is for problem number 2

                    // Call the Function to get the replies of the comment
                    getReplies(comment[0]);    // Send the ID of the comment
                }
            }
        }
    ajax.send("show=comments&photo="+photo);
}

function getReplies(commentID) {
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "path/some_php_file.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            // Get a string from PHP delimited by |
            var replies = ajax.responseText.split("|||");
            for (var i = 0; i < replies.length; i++){ 
                var reply = replies[i].split("|");
                if(reply[1] == "<?php echo $log_username; ?>") {        // If the user is the author of the reply
                    // Change the HTML of the replies
                    _('reply_'+ commentID).innerHTML += '<?php echo $replies_html; ?>';    // This is for problem number 2
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("show=replies&commentID="+commentID);
    }
}
```

some_php_file.php:

```
// Ajax calls this to load the clicked Photo --> getPhotos()
if (isset($_POST["show"]) && $_POST["show"] == "photos"){
    $picstring = "";
    $photo_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST["photo"]);
    $sql = "...";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $filename_1 = $row["..."];
        $filename_2 = $row["..."];
        $photoname = $row["..."];
        $picstring .= "$filename_1|$filename_2|$photoname|||";
    }
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    $picstring = trim($picstring, "|||");
    echo $picstring;
    exit();
}

// Ajax calls this to load the comments of the clicked photo --> getComments()
if (isset($_POST["show"]) && $_POST["show"] == "comments") {
    $commentstring = "";
    $photo_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST["photo"]);
    $sql = "...";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $commentid = $row["..."];
        $author = $row["..."];
        $postdate = $row["..."];
        $avatar = $row["..."];
        $user_image = '<img src="'.USERFILES.$author.'/'.$avatar.'" />';
        $data = $row["..."];
        $data = nl2br($data);
        $data = str_replace("&amp;","&",$data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $statusDeleteButton = '';
        if($author == $log_username) {      //  || $account_name == $log_username
            $statusDeleteButton = '...';
        }
        $commentstring .= "$commentid |$author|$data|$postdate|$user_image|$statusDeleteButton|||";
    }
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    $commentstring = trim($commentstring, "|||");
    echo $commentstring;
    exit();
}

// Ajax calls this to load the replies of the comments --> getReplies()
if (isset($_POST["show"]) && $_POST["show"] == "replies") {
    $commentstring = "";
    $comment_id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_POST["comment"]);
    // GATHER UP ANY STATUS REPLIES
    $status_replies = "";
    $sql = "...";
    $query_replies = mysqli_query($db_conx, "...");
    $query_replies = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $replynumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query_replies);
    if($replynumrows > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_replies, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $replyid = $row["…"];
            $replyauthor = $row["..."];
            $replydata = $row["..."];
            $avatar = $row["…"];
            $user_image = '<img src="'.USERFILES.$replyauthor.'/'.$avatar.'"/>';
            $replydata = nl2br($replydata);
            $replypostdate = $row["..."];
            $replydata = str_replace("&amp;","&",$replydata);
            $replydata = stripslashes($replydata);
            $replyDeleteButton = '';
            if($replyauthor == $log_username) { 
                $replyDeleteButton = '…';
            }
            $commentstring .= "$replyid|$replyauthor|$replydata|$replypostdate|$user_image|$replyDeleteButton|||";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($db_conx);
    $commentstring = trim($commentstring, "|||");
    echo $commentstring;
    exit();
}
```

Problem 1:

In my opinion is this variant not very fast . Especially the nested Javascript and the constant database queries are very awkward and not very timely to me.

So the question is if there are any suggestions to optimize the structure of the code or the code itself. Maybe there is also a more modular way to do it.

Problem 2:

The next problem is that the HTML-Construct of the comments are nearly the same in Javascript and in PHP (except the variables). So it was only logical for me to create a file which holds the HTML of the comments. Now the PHP and the Javascript can use the same file to construct the comments and their replies.

include.php:

```
$variable = "";

if (IS_AJAX) {
    $user = \'+variable[0]+\';
    $content = \'+variable[1]+\';
}

$variable .= '<div>';
$variable .=     '<a href="'.$user.'">'.$user.'</a>';
$variable .=        '<div><p>'.$content.'</p></div>';
$variable .= '</div>';
```

The problem is that the PHP-Variables has to be changed for the Javascript if this file is used by the ajax function. Therefor I have tried the following.

some_php_file.php:

```
$ajax = 0;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
{
    $ajax = 1;
}
define('IS_AJAX',$ajax);
```

But this does not working. Because I have read that this may be due to the server nor the info that I work with MAMP. Do you have any solutions for me?

Comment: Is this much better for performance?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use json structure when getting data from your server(http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), this should avoid any "split" stuff you have to do in your js later and there are other added advantages. Look into http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ too.
Also when you load all the images in the page :

```
   $style_list_right .= '<div id="right_'.$id.'"    onclick="getPhotos(\''.$album_id.'\',\''.$id.'\',\''.$u.'\')">';
    $style_list_right .=     '<img src="'.USERFILES . $u.'/'.$filename.'" />';
    $style_list_right .= '</div>';
```

You can probably do :

```
    $style_list_right .=     '<img src="'.USERFILES . $u.'/'.$filename.'" filename=$filename photoname="$photoname" albimid="$album_id" onclick="getPhotos(this)"/>';
```

So you have all the information in the first fetch, so when you click it, you can get those details from the image attribute(and not make ajax call at all). So you need just one ajax call to get the comments.
       Also its good for your ajax response to return just data(no html markups) because the amount of data you are getting from server is less which makes your ajax response faster, and then you can use js in the client to add those markup around your data much faster. Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Okay, what is with the second problem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do there, it seems like you are trying to set php variables from javascript values! Well that is just not possible, because php runs in your server and javascript runs in the client machine.